# Android: write a file with the content of a XmlPullParser

Tags: java, android

I have following file from a parser:

```
Resources res = getResources();
XmlResourceParser parser = res.getXml(R.xml.textvalues);
```

and I want to copy its content to my private storage to be able to work with it, I would like to do it like this:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = parser.ToString();

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

But parser.ToString doesn't return the XML content. Do I really need to iterate over the whole parser and use a StringBuilder to get my XML?

Thanks!

Comment: yes you have to. Or you can put the xml inside the assets folder

Comment: really?? :( I will use then the assets folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Assets folder (which I didn't knew previously, thanks @blackbelt) I was able to place any kind of file and access it without restrictions. Afterwards, I could copy its content in my private folder and work with the file.